# Django: 'Model' subclass inheritance

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've recently decided to learn the Django framework, and have started going through the official Django tutorials for the same. The code given in the official tutorials to create a model is as follows:

```
from django.db import models


class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Now, the code is pretty straightforward. However, I'm having troubling understanding the hierarchy of the 'Model' subclass that is being inherited inside each class model that is being defined:

```
models.Model
```

Where is the `Model` class located inside the `models` directory? I'm assuming this is a pretty basic question, so pardon my ignorance.

Comment: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/__init__.py#L9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using python manage.py shell

project directory$ `python manage.py shell`

project directory - Where `manage.py` module exists.

1) `models` is python module not a directory or package.

```
>>> from django.db import models
>>> models
<module 'django.db.models' from '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/__init__.pyc'>
```

2) [***Model***](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model) is class from `django.db.models.base` module.

```
>>> help(models.Model)


Help on class Model in module django.db.models.base:

class Model(__builtin__.object)
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __eq__(self, other)
 |  
 |  __hash__(self)
 |  
 |  __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
 |  
 |  __ne__(self, other)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Model` class itself is located in `django.db.models.base`. If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/db/models), the `models` module is actually just a folder, not a `models.py` file. However, the `Model` class, among other commonly used classes in the package are imported in [`__init__.py`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/__init__.py), and are therefore available as `django.db.models.<class>`.